# Sign In with another google account for firebase and adsense

Tags: firebase, admob, adsense, firebase-console

I am using another google account for google adsense and it's verified. Is it possible to integrate that account for admob with this one? 
I am using firebase in -> abc@gmail.com 
My adsense account is -> xyz@gmail.com

Answer (score 11):

I have the same issue with two different accounts for firebase and admob.
What I've found is this post in google groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Woe_vOdAsS4.
So it seems like it is possible to do that, but with some additional steps described in this reply - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/Woe_vOdAsS4/urnc38SAAwAJ

Summary:
Admob/adsense account should be added as other owner into the Firebase account:

1. Sign in to Firebase.
2. Click the Settings icon and select Permissions.
3. On the Permissions page, click Add member.
4. In the dialog, enter the user, domain, group, or service account you wish to add.
5. Select a role("owner") for the new member, and click Add.

Now you should be able to link your AdMob app to a new project as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I did what @kodlan suggested after which I started seeing the firebase project from my firebase account. - Great so far!
However after selecting the project and typing the right package info, when I pressed LINK,

I got an error:
"Can't link to Firebase. To continue, you’ll need the Edit role or Manage users role for this property in Google Analytics. Update permissions in Google Analytics"

To resolve this:

1. Go to the Firebase account by login as (original owner)
2. load the url: https://analytics.google.com/
3. In the left nav bar of analytics page, click on the "gear/settings" icon which has label "ADMIN"
4. In the resulting screen - on ADMIN tab, click on "Account User Management"
5. Click on the + icon to add another user (user of admob account)
6. Check all checkboxes (or at least Edit, Read, Analyse). I didnt select "manage user" it was still ok without this.
7. Save.
8. Now, go to the Admob login and link your App with the firebase project, it should go through ok!

Answer (score 0):

I had my Firebase application linked to the AdMob account that was blocked.
So when I tried to link the admob to my app it give me error that the same app already exists. And it was not possible to unlink the old AdMob account from the Firebase as it's only possible from AdMob itself.

My solution in this case (for Android app) is to:

1. Create new Firebase project and the app to it.
2. Give permission from new project to new AdMob account.
3. Link the AdMob to new Firebase project.
4. Unlink Google Play from the old Firebase project and link to the new one.
5. Update the upp with new google-services.json
6. Publish new version of the app to Play